# How can i use double quotes inside sql update query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fire following command

```
update employees set text_data="[Demo-Data value="mddhak"]";
```

I am getting following error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Answer (score -1):

You can use SINGLE QUOTES instead to achieve the same

update employees set text_data='[Demo-Data value="mddhak"]';

Comment: You could. But what if there were single quotes in the value?

Comment: You can use alternate single and double quotes.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. What do you mean by "alternate"?